# Django prefetch_related fields with nested select_related fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Im trying to fetch Team details with team members details also.So i prefetch_related team_member table which is linked to employee table and that is linked to User table. when i executed the code.It calls user table multiple times.Please help on this.Thanks in advance.

```
#query
queryset = Team.objects.prefetch_related("team_members__employee")\
            .prefetch_related("team_members__employee__user").filter(
            team_members__employee__id=employee.id)
```

#db call
SELECT ••• FROM "leavetracker_team" INNER JOIN "leavetracker_teammember" ON ("leavetracker_team"."id" = "leavetracker_teammember"."team_id") WHERE ("leavetracker_teammember"."employee_id" = 7 AND "leavetracker_team"."id" = 16) LIMIT 21
8.00
Sel Expl
+
SELECT ••• FROM "leavetracker_teammember" WHERE "leavetracker_teammember"."team_id" IN (16)
0.00
Sel Expl
+
SELECT ••• FROM "leavetracker_employee" WHERE "leavetracker_employee"."id" IN (2, 6, 7, 10, 12)
0.00
Sel Expl
+
SELECT ••• FROM "core_user" WHERE "core_user"."email" IN ('mohammedismailfayeez@gmail.com', 'dhanush@gmail.com', 'fayeezmohammed@gmail.com', 'rajini@gmail.com', 'vijay@gmail.com')
8.00
Sel Expl
+
SELECT ••• FROM "leavetracker_employee" LIMIT 1000
2 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.        7.99
Sel Expl
+
SELECT ••• FROM "core_user" WHERE "core_user"."email" = 'vjs@gmail.com' LIMIT 21
19 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.       0.00
Sel Expl
+
SELECT ••• FROM "core_user" WHERE "core_user"."email" = 'maj@gmail.com' LIMIT 21
19 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.       7.99
Sel Expl
+
SELECT ••• FROM "core_user" WHERE "core_user"."email" = 'vijay@gmail.com' LIMIT 21
19 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.       0.00
Sel Expl
+
SELECT ••• FROM "core_user" WHERE "core_user"."email" = 'dhanush@gmail.com' LIMIT 21
19 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve your prefetch, you can do `select_related` within TeamMember like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Team.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "team_members",
        queryset=TeamMembers.objects.select_related("employee__user")
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi, Still facing same issue

Comment: Then why did you mark it as answered?